# How to concatenate numbers with padding in R?

Tags: r, concatenation

I have this dataset of 8 integer variables of one or two digits and I wanna concatenate them, but pad the numbers with 1 digit with a 0 at the start.

For example, the first example on the image would become "1215020401010102".

I dont want full code solutions, just what functions would help me in this. I've been trying to make a fuction to use with sapply but haven't been sucessfull.

[image: Dataset]

Comment: It seems like you are basically using these as text values and possibly pasting them ... is that right?  Or are you multiplying them by the appropriate power of 10?   `x1 * 10^14 + x2* 10^12`  etc   .... also please don't paste images of data, make a small data set someone can copy and paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this data

```
set.seed(1)
(dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(10, 15, T), nrow = 5)))
#  V1 V2 V3
#1  3  9  3
#2  4 10  2
#3  6  7  7
#4 10  7  4
#5  3  1  8
```

We can use `do.call` with `paste0` and `lapply` with `formatC` here:

```
do.call(paste0, lapply(dat, formatC, width = 2, flag = "0"))
# [1] "030903" "041002" "060707" "100704" "030108"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option with `sprintf`

```
do.call(sprintf, c(dat, fmt = "%02d%02d%02d"))
#[1] "030903" "041002" "060707" "100704" "030108"
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>% 
   mutate_all(str_pad, pad = '0', width = 2) %>% 
   unite(V1, V1, V2, V3, sep='') 
   # or if there are many columns use
   # unite(V1, !!! rlang::syms(names(.)), sep='')
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(V1 = c(3L, 4L, 6L, 10L, 3L), V2 = c(9L, 10L, 7L, 
 7L, 1L), V3 = c(3L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -5L))
```